# To find the maximum correlation value from a csv file of 20000 rows efficiently in python

Tags: python, performance, numpy, loops, machine-learning

I have a CSV file with 12 columns and 20000 rows and 12 images of shape 100 * 100, i.e, 10000 pixels. I need to run each pixel across 20000 data points in a CSV file to find the maximum correlation. Here is my function:

```
def Corrlate(pixels):
  max_value = -1
  max_roc = 0
  max_val = 0
  if(len(pixels[pixels != 0]) == 0):
        max_soc = 0
  else: 
      for index, row in data.iterrows():

        val = [row['B2'], row['B3'], row['B4'],
               row['B5'], row['B6'], row['B7'], 
               row['B8'], row['B11'], row['B12']]
        corr = np.corrcoef(pixels, val)
        if (corr > max_value).any(): 
          max_value = corr
          max_soc = row['SOC']
          max_val = val

  return max_soc
pixel = [0.1459019176,0.209071098,0.2940336262,0.3246242805,0.349758679,0.375791541,0.3990873849,0.5312103156,0.4791704195]
data = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
Corrlate(pixel)
```

test.csv

```
Or.,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8,B11,B12,SOC
0,0.09985147853,0.1279325334,0.1735545485,0.1963891543,0.2143978866,0.2315615778,0.2477941219,0.3175400435,0.3072681177,91.1
1,0.1353946488,0.1938304482,0.2661696295,0.2920155645,0.3128841044,0.3351216611,0.3539684059,0.4850393799,0.4505173283,21.4
2,0.1307552092,0.2112897844,0.3084664959,0.3367929562,0.3613391345,0.3852476516,0.4031711988,0.5193408686,0.4661771688,15.6
.
.
.
.
.
20000,0.1307552092,0.2112897844,0.3084664959,0.3367929562,0.3613391345,0.3852476516,0.4031711988,0.5193408686,0.4661771688,15855.6
```

The above function needs to be run 10000 times for an image of shape 100*100. 
In my machine, it was taking 2.5 hours to complete the process. Is there any effective solution to run this process with less time.

Comment: How are we supposed to evaluate or test this function?  There's limits as to what most of us can do by simply reading code.  And describing the csv file is nearly useless. The function doesn't read a file; it takes some vague `pixels` object as argument, and references a global `data` object (again vague).  A `numpy` ndarray does not have a `iterrows` method.

Comment: Hello, I update my question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use apply instead of iterating over your rows, it's always pretty inefficient to do this.

It seems your are already using pandas, I would also recommend using the pandarallel library to distribute the apply method.

```
def func_to_apply(row) :
      val = [row['B2'],row['B3'],row['B4'],
             row['B5'],row['B6'],row['B7'],
             row['B8'],row['B11'],row['B12']]

      corr = np.corrcoef(randompixels,val)
      return corr

data["corr"] = data.apply(func_to_apply,axis=1)
data[data["corr"].max()==data["corr"]]["SOC"]
```

That would be the notdistributed way.

Using pandarallel :

```
from pandarallel import pandarallel
pandarallel.initialize()

data["corr"] = data.parallel_apply(func_to_apply,axis=1)
data[data["corr"].max()==data["corr"]]["SOC"]
```

Wrote the code without testing it but it should work, let me know if something is wrong or if that helped.

Comment: Hello Robin, thank you for your response. now I can able to run 5 times faster by using pandarallel.
I am getting the following error at data[data["corr"].max()==data["corr"]]["SOC"]
**ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()**

Comment: @chaitanyaivvala Pandarallel is a nice lib indeed but you could also gain a lot by changing your code I think.
That's weird because I tried my code in local and it's working correctly ... Are you sure you have closed the brackets at the right place ? That's just debugging at this point, I'm sure you can figure it out.